# Time complexity of mandelbrot set in term of big O notation

Tags: c++, big-o, mandelbrot

I'm trying to find the time complexity of a simple implementation of mandelbrot set. with following code

```
int main(){
    int rows, columns, iterations;
    rows = 22;
    columns = 72;
    iterations = 28;

    char matrix[max_rows][max_columns];

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        for(int c = 0; c < columns; ++c){
            complex<float> z;
            int itr = 0;
            while(abs(z) < 2 && ++itr < iterations)
                z = pow(z, 2) + decltype(z)((float)c * 2 / columns - 1.5,
                    (float)r * 2 / rows - 1);
            matrix[r][c]=(itr== iterations ? '*' : '.');
        }
    }
```

Now looking at above code i made some estimation for time complexity in terms of big O notation and want to know if it is correct or not

So we are creating a 2d array traversing it through nested loops and and at each element we are performing an operation and setting a value of that element, if we take n as input size we can say that greater the input the greater will be the complexity, so the time complexity for rowsxcolumns would be O(rxc) and then again we are traversing it for printout, so what would be the time complexity? is it O(rxc)+O(rxc) ? does the function itself have some effect on time complexity when we are doing multiplication and subtraction on rows and columns? If yes then how?

Comment: @hyde rxc mean the number of elements in matrix and the other is typing error that i will fix in edit.

Answer (score 2):

Almost, given `r` rows, `c` columns and `i` iterations then the running time is `O(r*c*i)`. This should be trivial to see if `abs(z)<2` is not there. But with this extra condition its not clear how many times will the inner `while` loop run in total. Yes, it will be less than `r*c*i` times, so `O(r*c*i)` is still the upper bound. But perhaps we might do better. Given that for any `r,c` you compute Mandelbrot set over the same domain with varying resolution then the while loop will run `k*r*c*i` times for some constant `k` which is somewhere between area-of-Mandelbrot-set-over-area-of-the-domain and 1 --> Running time of the code is `Θ(r*c*i)` and `O(r*c*i)` cannot be improved.

Had you computed the set over `[-c,c]x[-r,r]` domain with fixed resolution then for any `|z|>2` the `abs(z)<2` breaks after first iteration. Then `O(r*c*i)` would not be tight bound and this condition (as all loop conditions) should be considered if you want accurate estimation.

Please don't use `malloc`,  `std::vector` is safer.

Answer (score 1):

In big-O notation, O(rxc)+O(rxc) collapses to O(rxc).

Since the maximal iteration count is also an input variable, it has an influence on the complexity as well. In particular, the inner loop runs at most n iterations, therefore, your complexity is O(rxcxn).

All other operations are constant, in particular multiplication and addition of `complex<float>`. These operations by themselves are always O(1), which does not contribut to the overall complexity.